# Webservice schema validation not working

Tags: xml, web-services

I am trying to do xml validation but getting the below error while doing xml validation.

Can you please help me, why I am getting the error while validating

. Getting this error "cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'ObjectId'. One of '{LanguageCode}' is expected."

```
schema:
-------
<xs:complexType name="Paragraph">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="ParagraphId" type="tns:ParagraphId" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Name" type="string"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Description" type="string"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="SectionNumber" type="string"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Editable" type="xs:boolean"/> <!-- If Y then This Paragraph is editable. -->
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="ParagraphText" type="ref:swaRef"/>
            <xs:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="Status" nillable="true" type="tns:StatusType"/>
            <!-- retrieveParagraph() : List of variables of this paragraph and the following are retrieved based on this “ReturnVariable” flag. -->
            <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" name="Variables" nillable="false" type="tns:Variable"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="OldParagraphId" type="tns:ParagraphId"  maxOccurs="unbounded" /> <!-- It will be used to get effective time stamp of existing paragraph on which we are creating Modification -->
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="Action" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="LockedBy" type="string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <xs:complexType name="ParagraphId">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="CountryCode" type="tns:CountryCodeType" />
            <xs:element default="00" name="SubsidiaryCode" type="tns:SubsidiaryCodeType" />
            <xs:element name="LanguageCode" type="string" />
            <xs:element name="ObjectId" type="string" />
            <xs:element name="TextVersionId" type="string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType> 

xml:
---
<Paragraphs>
                <ParagraphId>
                    <CountryCode>111</CountryCode>
                    <SubsidiaryCode>01</SubsidiaryCode>
                    <LanguageCode>AAA</LanguageCode>
                    <ObjectId>MMMM</ObjectId>
                    <TextVersionId>1</TextVersionId>
                </ParagraphId>
                <Description>Title</Description>
                <SectionNumber>2</SectionNumber>
                <ParagraphText>cid:urn:uuid:FCA0989FBA745C0A771349097015870@apache.org</ParagraphText>
                <Status>Draft</Status>
                <OldParagraphId>
                    <CountryCode>111</CountryCode>
                    <SubsidiaryCode>01</SubsidiaryCode>
                    <ObjectId>1111</ObjectId>
                    <LanguageCode>ENU</LanguageCode>
                    <TextVersionId>1</TextVersionId>
                </OldParagraphId> 
            </Paragraphs>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your schema says that OldParagraphId must have a LanguageCode before the ObjectId, but in your instance they appear in the opposite order. You need to change either your schema or your instance.